# MS ACCESS VBA sendobject in email

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I have written an email system in ACCESS (Office 10, Windows 7) that works. But I would like to be able to send a formatted document or PDF, etc., something with graphics and text, as the email itself.  I have read up on SendObject but I think that sends the document as an attachment, and I would like it to be the email itself. I get emails like that, just want to know how its done.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Generally you need to use Outlook, and use it as an application, not just SendObject. There are quite a few references available.

Comment: @Fionnuala, I agree. Why reinvent the wheel? Access works seamlessly with its sibling Outlook using VBA. The same can be said of using Excel as a database when Access sits on the shelf. Let's use applications per their fundamentals. I usually find most questions on SO is not so much programming but process!

Answer (score 0):

To format the email body with graphics, images custom fonts, and font colors,  you would make your email body as HTML, for example:

```
Dim strBodyMsg AS String

strBodyMsg = "<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">"
strBodyMsg = strBodyMsg & "<head><title>...</title> </head>"
strBodyMsg = strBodyMsg & "<Body> "
strBodyMsg = strBodyMsg & "your email body message goes here"
strBodyMsg = strBodyMsg & "</Body>"
```

Also note when you open your email object in VBA.. here is the method

```
EmailObject.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```